# Bluetooth Adapter Crash/Freeze on sending Request

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluez, gatt

My bluetooth adapter freezes/crashes upon sending the 2nd request (really a command as I don't handle the response) to a LE Bluetooth device (a Parrot Drone). The bluetooth icon in the Ubuntu toolbar changes to having a lock on it so the device is paired but the application just hangs when sending the 2nd request.

It's incredibly difficult to determine what is exactly going wrong. What [Gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib), Gatt, Bluez functions can I use to query the status of the bluetooth adapter, the device log and the possible cause of the freeze? Any idea what could be going wrong?

I've tried `hcidump` but nothing useful is output, it doesn't output an error/text when the adapter fails.

Below is my code that uses `gattlib` ([link](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib)) to connect and communicate with the device. The application freezes when sending the 2nd request.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    gatt_connection_t* connection = gattlib_connect(NULL, MY_MAC_ADDRESS, BDADDR_LE_PUBLIC, BT_IO_SEC_LOW, 0, 0);
    if (connection == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to the bluetooth device.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connection Success\n\n");

    // Requests
    uint8_t buffer[100] = {0x01, 0x00};
    int ret = gattlib_write_char_by_handle(connection, 0x00c0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Send Cmd res %s: %d\n", (ret == 0) ? "Success":"Failed", ret);
    // Outputs: "Send Cmd res Success: 0"
    sleep(1); // Sleep for 1 second: incase I am flooding the device. Error occurs without sleeping aswell
    // Freeze/error occurs here and the bluetooth adapter icon shows a lock on it
    ret = gattlib_write_char_by_handle(connection, 0x00bd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Send Cmd res %s: %d\n", (ret == 0) ? "Success":"Failed", ret);
    sleep(1);

    ...
```

The above code is exactly the same as my `gatttool` commands which I have verified works and I can send movement commands to the drone. So I guess I can confirm it's not the drone thats the problem and that the bluetooth adapter can work when it wants to. Ie;

> sudo gatttool -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
>   connect
>   char-write-req 0x00c0 0100
>   char-write-req 0x00bd 0100
>   ...

Hcidump:

> HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.5
>   device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
>   - HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
>   - HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
>       LE Create Connection Cancel (0x08|0x000e) ncmd 1
>   - HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
>   - HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
>       LE Connection Update (0x08|0x0013) status 0x00 ncmd 1

Comment: If the Bluetooth icon is showing, it means the Bluetooth service is running. Try to stop it (sudo service bluetooth stop) and see if it works. When I was developing a BLE application I could only get it to work without this service running.

Comment: @LasseMeyer thanks I'll give that a go. Its seems that the bluetooth adapter or bluetooth in c is very finicky. Sometimes when I do `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` it will timeout so I've to manually `sudo hciconfig hci0 down` `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`. Didn;t know about the service so I'll give that a go.

Comment: @LasseMeyer no luck. I've killed the service, run my application and the same error occurs. I also killed the service again, reset and ran my application but the error still occurs.